# RSpec: Testing logger messages for block syntax

Tags: ruby, logging, rspec

I currently use a logger in the following way:

```
def log_stuff
  logger.info { 'Info log message' }
  logger.debug { expesive_action }
end
```

But I would like to know if the logger receives the correct message with RSpec.

If I would just pass the logging line to the input this would have been easy:

```
# logger.info('Info log message')
expect(logger_mock).to receive(:info).with('Info log message')
```

But I couldn't figure out a way I could do something like this with the block syntax.

I specifically want to use this syntax, so that `expensive_action` only gets called when the log level is set to DEBUG.

Comment: And it's too onerous to just calculate the expensive operation before the test so you can test... What, that the debug function works?

Comment: I don't get the question. I can of course run expensive_action in test, but I currently don't know how to verify the result against the evaluation of the block.

Comment: I need to compare an input value to the method. That's easy with a mock. However only if I have a value passed into a method, not a block. So can you provide a concrete example for what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not *that* difficult, though a tad trickier than vanilla expectations:

```
  expect(logger_mock).to receive(:info) do |&block|
    expect(block.call).to eq('Info log message')
  end
```

in this case, `&block` in your spec is simply the block you have in `logger.info` call. So you must explicitly call it, and then set another expectation on the return value. That's how I do it, at least.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**

Based on @EdvardM's excellent answer:

The general case looks like this:

```
  expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:info) do |&block|
    expect(block.call).to match(/regex matching the log message/)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's quite tricky because the block is lazy evaluated.

Sometimes you can solve this by mocking at a lower level. For example, `info` internally calls `add` passing the type of log. However, even in this case, mocking add doesn't help you because the block is passed verbatim and it's not evaluated.

At this point, you may want to stub the execution of `expensive_action` and check if the action has been called or not. Of course, this solution would not work if you just return a string in the block, but only if you call another method you can mock.